# The controller is not allowed by this plugin

Tags: php, typo3, typo3-6.2.x

I try to add a new controller which has one action called `confirmAgbAction`.

```
<?php
namespace Eddcapone\MyExtension\Controller;

/**
 * CustomController
 */
class CustomController extends \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Mvc\Controller\ActionController 
{

    /**
     * action list
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function confirmAgbAction()
    {
        echo "<p>HALLO WELT</p>";    
    }
}
```

I even added it to `ext_localconf.php`

```
<?php
if (!defined('TYPO3_MODE')) {
    die('Access denied.');
}

\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::configurePlugin(
    'Eddcapone.' . $_EXTKEY,
    'Myfilelist',
    array(
        'Category' => 'list,show',
        'File' => 'show',
        'Download' => 'download',
        'Custom' => 'confirmAgb'
    ),
    // non-cacheable actions
    array(
        'Category' => 'list,show',
        'File' => 'topFive',
        'Download' => 'download',
        'Custom' => 'confirmAgb'
    )
);
```

This is how I call the action in the template:

```
<f:link.action controller="Custom" action="confirmAgb" pluginName="Myfilelist" class="mbButton">Download</f:link.action>
```

However, i always get:

`#1313855173: The controller "Custom" is not allowed by this plugin. Please check for TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::configurePlugin() in your ext_localconf.php.`

Comment: the stupidest question in the beginning: do you have cleared the Cache in the Install Tool with the "Clear all cache"-Button?

Comment: Clear the cache from install tool

Comment: Nah it's not a stupid question ;) yes I cleared all 3 caches and even cleared `typo3temp`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two common possibilities for your error:

1. You use a flexform to embed your plugin. Either you have not added `Custom->confirmAgb` to the allowed calls in your flexform or you have added it but did not update the plugin (plugin configuration only updates when you save the plugin/tt_content element)
2. You have two plugins on the page and the error is triggered by the other plugin because there the `controller->action` combination is not allowed.

PS: try adding this to your TS (setup.txt) and the plugins now should pick the default action if the given one is not found:

```
plugin.tx_yourextensionmvc.callDefaultActionIfActionCantBeResolved = 1
```

There could be more uncommon cases

Comment: You were right, i was using two plugins and the problem was because of a flexform. The developers on typo3 slack recommended me not to use `switchablecontrolleractions`, so I deleted it from the flexforms. This did not helped first, only after I also saved the plugin/tt_content. Thanks!

Comment: There is no need to remove the flexform functionality, I am pretty sure that you can also do a workaround in Typo3 6.2.x. Try adding this to your extension setup.txt: 

    plugin.tx_yourextension {
 mvc.callDefaultActionIfActionCantBeResolved = 1
    }

Comment: While those are likely possibilties, there are definitly more then those two options of what goes wrong. This is one of those error that have a lot of different reasons.

Answer (score 1):

You should absolutely avoid using $_EXTKEY in configurePlugin and other Extbase contexts. Extbase requires the `Vendor.ExtensionName` format - $_EXTKEY is in the `lowercase_underscored` format. Defining those parameters as hardcoded values should solve your problem with resolving controllers for your given plugin.

To be precise: use `Eddcapone.Myextension` as extension name parameter in your command(s) to register/configure plugins.

Comment: Thank you for the infos! Okay I've changed every occurence of `$_EXTKEY` in my whole extension to `MyExtension`, but I still get:

`#1313855173: The controller "Custom" is not allowed by this plugin. Please check for TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::configurePlugin() in your ext_localconf.php.`
So the problem must be somewhere else.

Comment: Update for anyone reading: cause was previous use of switchableControllerActions, additionally reuse of the content element record which contained switchableControllerActions *values* after they were removed from the *schema*. Cleaning the record field solved it.