# How to call a controller action on every page request

Tags: typo3, extbase

I have a Plugin with various actions, one of the Actions I would like to call every time a page is requested. I tried it [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44858283/typo3-insert-plugin-on-every-pages) way but when I have the plugin on the same page (lets say it's a Contact form) Then the Plugin didn't know the other Actions, so I have to include every time all actions in the `switchableControllerActions`.

Is there maybe an another way? Maybe register the Action of the Controller in some kind of hook?

Answer (score 2):

Probably you can create lib object of the extension, Take a look at below user function:

```
lib.myData = USER
lib.myData {
  userFunc = TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Core\Bootstrap->run
  extensionName = Ext
  pluginName = pluginName
  vendorName = MyVendor

  switchableControllerActions {
        MyController{
          1 = myAct
        }
  }

  settings < plugin.tx_ext.settings
  settings {
        // Your settings
  }
}
```

Now, you can call the lib object to the fluid template (As you need for each page) you can add this object to the main page layout.

[Here](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/news/AdministratorManual/BestPractice/IntegrationWithTypoScript/Index.html#add-news-by-typoscript) Georg Ringer has created same code to render news listing with Typoscript.

Hope this will help you!

Comment: Well th's exactly what I tried to do. But then the other Actions are not working and typo3 tells me that the actions are not allowed.

Comment: Its not an issue with user function I guess, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40150145/the-controller-x-is-not-allowed-by-this-plugin?answertab=active#tab-top) is the solution by Dimitri L. might help you.

Comment: Somehow I think that this is not this what I really need.
It starts that I didnt need a view for example. Just to describe the functionality of the action I try to call, I want to delete some cookies and redirect the user to a specific page when he containes a special cookie.

Answer (score 1):

OK I've recieved a hint and that's the Solution:

```
20 = USER_INT
20 {
    userFunc = Vendor\Extension\UserFunc\Class->function
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use FlexForms to set a preset Controller->Action. So even if you use a plugin twice on one page you can control the Controller->Action of each Plugin via FlexForm.

Maybe this helps a well:
[Multiple controllers in an extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56112212/multiple-controllers-in-an-extension/56135820#56135820)

Comment: I think that wouldn't work. Because the Action which he tells me is missing is not the Action taht is initial there to show the form. It's some kind of Login. In the Form I have a action to handle the login process. "loginMail" and that action he tells me is not available.